# Calculo em python

Tags: python, matemática

Como faço isso?

```python
VAL[0] = 9.999839999244

VAL[1] = 349.0

VALUE = VAL[0]) * 10.0 ** float(VAL[1])
#Error (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Comment: olá este é o site do SO em português, as perguntas aqui devem ser feitas nesse idioma

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Além disso sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045), [ask], [mcve] e [help].

Comment: Especificamente no seu caso use uma biblioteca externa que trabalhe com aritmética arbitrária.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Boa noite, dei uma estuda aqui neste código e fiz algumas alterações. ver se é oque deseja.

Código alterado:

VAL0 = 9.999839999244
VAL1 = 34

VALUE = (VAL0 * 10.0) ** float(VAL1)

print(VALUE)

Codigo Original:

VAL[0] = 9.999839999244

VAL[1] = 349.0

VALUE = VAL[0]) * 10.0 ** float(VAL[1])

Removi os [] que tinha no código e também o float no código

Comment: Você eliminou o erro do problema original ao elevar ~100 a 34 em vez de 349. O erro mostrado na pergunta ocorre porque o Python não consegue lidar com números tão grandes, e na sua versão você está gerando um resultado muito menor, com que o python consegue lidar. Por isso sua resposta está sendo negativada...